# ipad iOS 17 crash on FBSScene

Tags: ios

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  FrontBoardServices             0x38b8 -[FBSScene _updateClientSettings:withTransitionContext:] + 1092
1  FrontBoardServices             0x340c -[FBSScene updateClientSettingsWithTransitionBlock:] + 116
2  FrontBoardServices             0x336c -[FBSScene updateClientSettingsWithBlock:] + 124
3  UIKitCore                      0xac510 -[FBSScene(UIApp) updateUIClientSettingsWithBlock:] + 168
4  UIKitCore                      0xac340 __39-[UIWindow _noteOverlayInsetsDidChange]_block_invoke + 248
5  UIKitCore                      0xab004 -[_UIAfterCACommitBlock run] + 72
6  UIKitCore                      0xaade8 -[_UIAfterCACommitQueue flush] + 164
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x26a8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x4300 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
9  libdispatch.dylib              0x12998 _dispatch_main_queue_drain + 984
10 libdispatch.dylib              0x125b0 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 44
11 CoreFoundation                 0x3720c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 16
12 CoreFoundation                 0x33f18 __CFRunLoopRun + 1996
13 CoreFoundation                 0x33668 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 608
14 GraphicsServices               0x35ec GSEventRunModal + 164
15 UIKitCore                      0x22c2b4 -[UIApplication _run] + 888
16 UIKitCore                      0x22b8f0 UIApplicationMain + 340
17 XXX                           0x1890428 main + 25 (main.m:25)
```

ipad iOS 17 crash on FBSScene： [FBSScene _updateClientSettings:withTransitionContext:]

Comment: Please provide more information. At least the reason of the crash, not just the stacktrace.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.